# Query gets very slows if i add a where

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.emp_id,s.name, s.department,s.register, z.Compoff_Count as Extra,  ifnull(COUNT(DISTINCT TO_DAYS(a.punchdate)),0) as Monthly_Count
FROM machinedata a left join

(SELECT a.emp_id, ifnull(COUNT(DISTINCT TO_DAYS(a.punchdate)),0) as Compoff_Count
FROM machinedata a 
RIght  JOIN time_dimension c on c.db_date = a.punchdate 
where (  year(c.db_date) = 2016 and  month(c.db_date) = 8   and (c.holiday_flag = 't' or c.weekend_flag ='t' ))
GROUP BY a.emp_id) Z
on z.emp_id = a.emp_id
RIght  JOIN time_dimension c on c.db_date = a.punchdate 
left join emp s on s.emp_id = a.emp_id  

where (year(c.db_date) = 2016 and  month(c.db_date) = 8  and c.holiday_flag = 'f' and c.weekend_flag ='f' )
GROUP BY emp_id
```

---

The above query works fine.. but if i add s.department='yes' in the last where the query takes more than 40 seconds.

What shall i do to improve the query performance ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html

Comment: What is the size of the tables involved ? What are the structures ? Can you use EXPLAIN with your query and post the result ?

Comment: possibly your request without department="yes" was simply cached, please provide EXPLAIN output for both queries

Comment: https://s17.postimg.org/4ck5pri4f/Capture.png

Comment: Please edit your question with the data in textual format as it is an important part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial query can be simplified I believe by using "conditional aggregates" which places case expressions inside the count() function. This avoids repeated sans of data and unnecessary joins to derived tables.

You should also avoid using functions on data to suit where clause conditions i.e. Instead of YEAR() and MONTH() simply use date boundaries. This allows an index on the date column to be used in the query execution.

I'm not sure if you really need to use TO_DAYS() but I suspect it isn't needed either.

```
SELECT
      a.emp_id
    , s.name
    , s.department
    , s.register
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (c.holiday_flag = 't' OR
            c.weekend_flag = 't') THEN c.db_date END) AS Compoff_Count
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT (c.holiday_flag = 't' OR
            c.weekend_flag = 't') THEN a.punchdate END) AS Monthly_Count
FROM time_dimension c
LEFT JOIN machinedata a ON c.db_date = a.punchdate
LEFT JOIN emp s ON a.emp_id = s.emp_id
WHERE c.db_date >= '2016-08-01'
      AND c.db_date < '2016-09-01'
GROUP BY
      a.emp_id
    , s.name
    , s.department
    , s.register
```

If this re-write produces correct results then you could try adding **and s.department='yes'** into the where clause to assess the impact. If it is still substantially slower then get an explain plan and add it to the question. The most likley cause of slowness is lack of an index but without an explain plan it's not possible to be certain.

Please note that this suggestion is just that; and is prepared without sample data and expected results.

Comment: Great. By the way, it is an unwritten convention - to save yourself from major headaches - that one does not use right joins.  Right join is legit syntax, but in practice it gets hard to follow, especially if you do it more than once in a single query. Just a tip. No more than that.